# spark accumulators - which is executed in executor Vs the code executed in driver

Tags: apache-spark

It is mentioned like in " Spark In Action" Book ,

> You can access an accumulator’s value only from within the driver. If you try to access it from an executor, an exception will be thrown.

I am learning spark and come across the above. How it could be differentiated or recognize the code which is executed in executor Vs the code executed in driver.

Further, the author referred the above with the following code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnMbL.png

Answer (score 2):

Transformations run on executors & actions runs on driver other words  tasks(transformation) executes on the Workers(Executors) and when action(take/collect) is called it brings back the data at the Driver. to return value.

When any action is called on the RDD, Spark creates the DAG and submits to the DAG scheduler,DAG scheduler divides operators into stages of tasks. A stage is comprised of tasks based on partitions of the input data. The DAG scheduler pipelines operators together.

The Stages are passed on to the Task Scheduler.The task scheduler launches tasks via cluster manager.(Standalone/Yarn/Mesos).

Comment: tthanks for your quick response. However, the question was to know how to find out  (or recognize) part of the code will be executed in driver vs part of the code will be executed in executor

Comment: Transformations run on executors & actions runs on driver because it needs to return value.

Comment: Perfect !! it is hidden from the user where the code is running, in that case how to write the code to execute the code in the executor vs to execute in the driver ( PS . Please refer the pic posted in the question)